# Docker Compose Adminer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, adminer

I want to use the adminer image that is raised with the following docker command:

```
docker run \
    --rm
    -p 8000:80
    -e MEMORY=512M
    -e UPLOAD=4096M
    dockette/adminer:full
```

My docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version: '2.4'
services:

  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb-prueba
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql    
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_prueba'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'admin'
    ports:
      - 2000:3306
  adminer:
    container_name: adminerprueba
    image: dockette/adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      - UPLOAD=4096M
      - MEMORY=512M
volumes:
  mariadb-data:
```

The problem is that it runs but when I do `localhost:8000` the system appears to be down.

Am I missing something in the docker-compose

Comment: First step would be to look at the logs and see if there's any hint.

Comment: There are the logs
`[8] [Fri May  6 07:32:37 2022] PHP 8.0.13 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:80) started`
[9] [Fri May  6 07:32:37 2022] PHP 8.0.13 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:80) started
[10] [Fri May  6 07:32:37 2022] PHP 8.0.13 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:80) started
[11] [Fri May  6 07:32:37 2022] PHP 8.0.13 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:80) started[7] [Fri May  6 07:32:37 2022] PHP 8.0.13 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:80) started

Answer (score 0):

Your docker compose file works fine for me.

I can access http://localhost:8000/ just fine and it brings up Adminer 4.8.1. As long as I put `mariadb` in as the server, admin/admin, it attaches to it.

Couple of things to try:

1. [Because YAML parses numbers in the format xx:yy as a base-60 value](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports), you may want to quote your ports.
2. You may already have something listening on 80 (try it out when the compose file is down)
3. Even though yours works fine for me, you might want to grab the [official image with instructions](https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer/).

[image]